# MVC Core: Display another property based on primary key

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a model with a foreign key of another table.  In this case, the waiver object is related to an office object

```
public class Waiver
    {
        public int WaiverID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select an Office")]
        [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please select an Office")]
        public int OfficeID { get; set; }
        //...other properties
}
```

I have a search result that filters by the OfficeID:

```
 IEnumerable<Waiver> waiverList = repository.Waivers
                .Where(wl => waiverNum == 0 || wl.WaiverID == waiverNum)
                .Where(wl => officeId == 0 || wl.OfficeID == officeId)
//...other search criteria
```

This is displayed in my View by:

```
@model IEnumerable<Waiver>

@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td class="text-right">@item.WaiverID</td>
            <td class="text-right">@item.OfficeID></td>
@* other display columns *@
```

While the Waiver object passed to the View has the OfficeID property, I would like to display the Name property in the Office model as it is more useful to the user.  How can I accomplish this?

My EF Repository is set up as:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Waiver.Models

//This class implements the IWaiverRepository and gets its data using Entity Framework Core
{
    public class EFWaiverRepository : IWaiverRepository
    {


        private ApplicationDbContext context;

        public EFWaiverRepository(ApplicationDbContext ctx)
        {
            context = ctx;
        }


        public IEnumerable<Waiver> Waivers => context.Waivers;
        public IEnumerable<Office> Offices => context.Offices;

        //*****Waiver Methods*****
        public void SaveWaiver(Waiver waiver)
        {
            //if the waiver number is 0, create a new waiver
            if (waiver.WaiverID == 0)
            {
                context.Waivers.Add(waiver);
            }
            //if there wavier number exists, save the changes to the database
            else {
                Waiver dbEntry = context.Waivers.FirstOrDefault(w => w.WaiverID == waiver.WaiverID);
                if (dbEntry != null)
                {
                    dbEntry.Requestor = waiver.Requestor;
                    dbEntry.RequestorEmail = waiver.RequestorEmail;
                    dbEntry.OfficeID = waiver.OfficeID;
                    dbEntry.RequestDate = waiver.RequestDate;
                    dbEntry.System = waiver.System;
                    dbEntry.Source = waiver.Source;
                    dbEntry.Requirement = waiver.Requirement;
                    dbEntry.MitigationPlan = waiver.MitigationPlan;
                    dbEntry.FinalAssessment = waiver.FinalAssessment;
                    dbEntry.Status = waiver.Status;
                    //get the signatures
                    dbEntry.PmSignature = waiver.PmSignature;
                    dbEntry.PmSignDate = waiver.PmSignDate;
                }
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public Waiver DeleteWaiver(int waiverID)
        {
            Waiver dbEntry = context.Waivers
                .FirstOrDefault(w => w.WaiverID == waiverID);
            if (dbEntry != null)
            {
                context.Waivers.Remove(dbEntry);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            return dbEntry;
        }

        //*****Office Methods*****
        public void SaveOffice(Office office)
        {
            //if the ID=0, its a new entry. Add to db
            if (office.OfficeID == 0)
            {
                context.Offices.Add(office);
            } else
            {
                Office dbEntry = context.Offices.FirstOrDefault(o => o.OfficeID == office.OfficeID);
                if (dbEntry != null)
                {
                    dbEntry.Name = office.Name;
                    dbEntry.SiteID = office.SiteID;
                }
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public Office DeleteOffice(int officeID)
        {
            Office dbEntry = context.Offices
                .FirstOrDefault(o => o.OfficeID == officeID);
            if (dbEntry != null)
            {
                context.Offices.Remove(dbEntry);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            return dbEntry;
        }
```

where the EFRepository implements:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Waiver.Models
{
    public interface IWaiverRepository
    {
        IEnumerable<Waiver> Waivers { get; }
        IEnumerable<Office> Offices { get; }
        IEnumerable<Site> Sites { get; } 

        void SaveWaiver(Waiver waiver );
        Waiver DeleteWaiver(int waiverID);

        void SaveOffice(Office office);
        Office DeleteOffice(int officeID);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using entity framework core? What version is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lazy loading is not yet possible with EF Core, so that you need to include related entities. The solution should look like below.

```
public class Waiver
{
    public int WaiverID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select an Office")]
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please select an Office")]
    public int OfficeID { get; set; }

    public virtual Office Office { set;get;}
}
```

`repository.Waivers` need to change as below.

**Updated**

```
IEnumerable<Waiver> waiverList = repository.Waivers.Where(wl => waiverNum == 0 || wl.WaiverID == waiverNum).Where(wl => officeId == 0 || wl.OfficeID == officeId)
```

//...other search criteria

```
@model IEnumerable<Waiver>
<table>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td> @item.WaiverID </td>
        <td> @item.OfficeID </td>
        <td> @item.Office.Name </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

**Update**

Change `public IEnumerable<Waiver> Waivers => context.Waivers;` to

```
public IEnumerable<Waiver> Waivers => context.Waivers.Include(o => o.Office);
```

If this did not work, you need to check your db context class and correctly set mappings between `Waivers` and `Office` tables inside model bindings.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This makes sense, but I get an error on the "Include" method as it is not recognized.  Is this in an updated EF?  I am using 1.1.1 but get an error when I try to update to EFCore 2.0.0

Comment: No, this should work on your version, check this official article. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data. Only need these two reference. using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore; and 
using System.Linq;

Comment: I think you are using repository pattern, so that you need to change your repository to support include functionality when retrieving data.

Comment: I'm new to MVC core ; I've looked around and found some info on the subject, but it isn't immediately clear to me how to implement an Include() method within EF.

Comment: Can your post your repository code, I will see how I can help.

Comment: This worked! Thank you!  For anyone else, the "Include" issue was resolved by including "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;" namespace within the EF repository

Answer (score 0):

Add a `virtual` navigational property on your Waiver class of `Office` type.

```
public class Waiver
{
    public int WaiverID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select an Office")]
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please select an Office")]
    public int OfficeID { get; set; }

    public virtual Office Office { set;get;}
}
```

Now in your view, you can access the Office property of each Waiver item

```
@model IEnumerable<Waiver>
<table>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td> @item.WaiverID </td>
        <td> @item.OfficeID </td>
        <td> @item.Office.Name </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

EF will load the Office property for your waiver items.